# Continous fade in and fade out

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

Im trying to fade in and out of a light node I have created I just dont know where to call the function accordingly so it will continously fade in and out. Never tried animating anything here is what I have.

```
- (void)fadeOutIn:(UIView *)view duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"//*" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"light1"]) {
            [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:5 delay:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                node.alpha = 0;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
          }];
        }
    }];
}
```

where should I call this function?that is fades in and out continously?
Should it be called within an action?
Thank You

Comment: when you want to start fad in out ? on the click or when view will appear?

Comment: Yes i want to start fadeout when the view appears then fade back in as long as the view is still there. Within time increments of 2 seconds so continously

Comment: Call your function on viewDidAppear and also add another animation block in completion block for continue fade in out. Hope it helps.

Comment: solution work or not?

Comment: Thank you one last question. I have my viewController which calls my mainScene.m is there anyway I can place viewDidAppear in mainScene.m? Because when i place that function in viewController I get an error saying no visible interface for ViewController declares the sector enumarateChild

Comment: Yes you can responding to view events on every implementation(.m) file.[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class) link provides you more knowledge on viewcontrollers events

Answer (score 2):

Use this for Continue fade in out.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
    node.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{  
        node.alpha = 1;
    } completion:nil];
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        [objAnimate setAlpha:1.0];

        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
            [objAnimate setAlpha:0.0];
        } completion:nil];
    }
```

This will create continuous fade in and out for your object when it appears. If you want to create programmatically a custom object and then use this code then do it after your custom object is added in your view as below (example):

```
    objAnimate = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 200, 40)];
    objAnimate.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [objAnimate setAlpha:1.0];
    [self.view addSubview:objAnimate];
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
            [objAnimate setAlpha:0.0];
        } completion:nil];
```

The view starts animating as soon as its added in your view.